# Can't parse tag from XML using Python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I can't figure out how to get tag `Characters` from XML which is a part of `DOCX` file. The `DOCX` file contains multiple files including `app.xml`. I want to get tag or property `<Characters>` from this `XML`.

[image]

```
from lxml import etree

def docx_get_characters_number(path):
    document = zipfile.ZipFile(path)
    xml_content = document.read('docProps/app.xml')
    document.close()
    root = etree.fromstring(xml_content,etree.XMLParser())
    return root.xpath('.//Characters')
```

This function returns `[]` but I can't figure out why.

To test, whether the parser works, I've printed `root.xpath('.//*')` which returned this:

```
[<Element {http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties}Template at 0x3a8d260>, <Element {http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties}TotalTime at 0x3a8d288>, <Element {http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties}Pages at 0x3a8d2b0>, <Element {http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties}Words at 0x3a8d2d8>, <Element {http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties}Characters at 0x3a8d300>, <Element {http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties}Application at 0x3a8d328>, <Element {http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties}DocSecurity at 0x3a8d350>, <Element {http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties}Lines at 0x3a8d378>, ... etc.
```

Do you know where is the problem?

---

### EDIT:

I've found a way how to do that but it's not elegant and I think I should keep looking for another way but:

```
def docx_get_characters_number(path):
    document = zipfile.ZipFile(path)
    xml_content = document.read('docProps/app.xml')
    document.close()
    these_regex="<Characters>(.+?)</Characters>"
    pattern=re.compile(these_regex)
    return re.findall(pattern,xml_content)[0]
```

Comment: Why don't you try this XPath: `'/Properties/Characters'` or when the root node is already the Properties element `'/Characters'` - are there additional requirements or is the retrieval of the seeked 13088 character count only an example to help us help you better for a more generic XPath usage?

Comment: @Dilettant It does not work too. Returns []. But I found a way to find that using regex. And yes, I'm looking just for tag Characters - it's text

Comment: Thanks. Then maybe you can accept my answer and good to know you found a hack around - regex parsing xml files is not always cool, but a fixed tag in a somehow fixed schema like for office elements (character count) should be a reasonable choice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use etree module like this:

```
#to load the xml
from lxml import etree
doc=etree.parse("the path to your xml file")


#to find the Characters tab
doc.find("Characters").text
```

Of course if `Characters` wasn't a root node, you'd need to put the full path. Something like `Property/Character`

Answer (score 1):

This is a frequently asked problem related to *default namespace*. Your XML has default namespace declared at the root element :

```
xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties}"
```

This means, all elements without prefix, including your target element `<Characters>`, are considered in that namespace. The proper way to reference element in namespace would be to map a prefix to the namespace URI, and use that prefix accordingly in the XPath :

```
.....
ns = {'d': 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties'}
return root.xpath('d:Characters', namespaces=ns)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem in this case is in the xml declaration of the file. The attribute standalone may only contain the value yes or no. So lxml on my machine bails out during parsing stage ...

When I use the following file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Properties>
    <Characters>13088</Characters>
</Properties>
```

the following script does find the character count containing element:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
"""Explain here what this module has to offer."""
from __future__ import print_function

from lxml import etree as et


def docx_get_characters_number(path_unzipped):
    """Changed to focus on parsing the XML file."""
    with open(path_unzipped, 'rt') as f:
        xml_string = f.read()
    return et.fromstring(xml_string, et.XMLParser()).xpath('.//Characters')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path_unzipped = 'docProps/app.xml'
    print(docx_get_characters_number(path_unzipped))
```

So it gives:

```
[<Element Characters at 0x108bcb518>]
```

In contrast replacing in the xml declaration the value of standalone attribute from "yes" to "true" gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/some_place/so_parse_characters_xpath.py", line 17, in <module>
  print(docx_get_characters_number(path_unzipped))
File "/some_place/so_parse_characters_xpath.py", line 13, in docx_get_characters_number
  return et.fromstring(xml_string, et.XMLParser()).xpath('.//Characters')
File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 3213, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:77697)
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1819, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:116494)
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1707, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:115144)
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1079, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:109543)
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 573, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:103404)
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:105058)
File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 613, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:103967)
```

lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: standalone accepts only 'yes' or 'no', line 1, column 50